# Couldn't spawn child process: C:/bugzilla/admin.cgi

Tags: apache, perl, xampp, cgi, bugzilla

I don't know what the problem is, after successfully setting up Bugzilla and log-in, when I clicked any of the link like Administration it returns this error message:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
couldn't create child process: 720002: admin.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13
```

I checked the Apache error log and got this:

```
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.339205 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.448624 2017] [core:warn] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.641664 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.704265 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.704265 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.704265 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:21.719891 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9152:tid 500] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7304
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:22.692898 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 7304:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:23.017759 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 7304:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:23.080268 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7304:tid 512] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:28.707037 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7304:tid 1848] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:60709] couldn't create child process: 720002: admin.cgi
[Mon Feb 13 13:10:28.707037 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7304:tid 1848] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:60709] AH01223: couldn't spawn child process: C:/bugzilla/admin.cgi
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> [kehinde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42204578/5157221) already mention that Bugzilla is developed in Linux environment.

You should change the path in all `.cgi` files on line 1 from

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
```

to

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -T
```

Then restart your Apache/WAMP Server. It works!

Comment: It worked, but no need to restart apache, if you are changing only files, not conf.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple issue, just have to change the installation Perl directory to point to where the bin folder at the top of each .cgi files since Bugzilla is developed in Linux environment. `#!/Perl64/bin/perl.exe -T`

Comment: what actually can i do.?

Answer (score -2):

Just place a double quotation after #!
Also remember to close your quotation
E.g
#!"C:\your path to python\python.exe"